# Xcode - issue of push view by segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I want to use push segue to change view. Also, I want to past few data to destination view. Before the segue change view, I want to pop a alertview with textfield to check user password. If match, it will change the view. If not, it will stop the push segue.

I know that if want to prevent the push segue to do something first need to use the below method, but it cannot get the `segue.destinationViewController`. Is anyway can replace the `segue.destinationViewController`?

> `- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`

Moreover, can I get the alertView textfield result in the `- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` method?

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
   if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"chatSegue"]) {
       NSLog(@"should");
       NSString *plock = [Server getUserDatawithkey:@"plock"];
       if ([plock isEqual:@"1"]) {

           UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Privacy Lock" message:@"Please enter your password:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
           alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
           UITextField * addFriendField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
           addFriendField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
           addFriendField.placeholder = @"Enter your password";
           alert.tag = ALERT_TAG_PW;
           [alert show];
           // Can I get the alertView textfield result at here?

           NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
           friendCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

           // Is anyway to replace the segue.destinationViewController?
           chatViewController *cvc = segue.destinationViewController;
           cvc.fid = cell.fid.text;
           cvc.title = cell.f_name.text;
           return YES;
       }
       return NO;
   }
   return YES;
}
```

Is somebody can help me? Thanks!

Comment: so what is the problem here?

Comment: you can't replace dest view controller if you are using by segue. You can push by programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating the alert in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` you should create it somewhere else (whatever is calling your push) and depending on the resulting action of that alert perform `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier" sender:self];`

To handle the result of your alert you want to use the `UIAlertViewDelegate` and the method `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`.

Might look something like this...

```
- (void)getServerStuff {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Privacy Lock" message:@"Please enter your password:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField * addFriendField = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    addFriendField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    addFriendField.placeholder = @"Enter your password";
    alert.tag = ALERT_TAG_PW;
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertView.tag == ALERT_TAG_PW) {
        if(buttonIndex == 0) {
          [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushViewIdentifier" sender:self];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
          //Do Nothing
        }
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushViewIdentifier" sender:self]) {
        ChatViewController *cvc = (ChatViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        cvc.property = self.someProperty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your explanation. @TheSD If I use your way to receive the result of the alert textfield and change view, how can I pass some data from A ViewController to B ViewController?  `- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` is missing the `(UIStoryboardSegus *) segue`. So,  I can't set `chatViewController *cvc = segue.destinationViewController;` to define B ViewController variables.

Comment: @JacksonNg could you please mark my answer as correct